# list storage ACL via Service pricipal

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-rbac

i want to run this [API - Path(get - properties)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/get-properties) but rather than using SAS, Access Key. I want to use AD based authentication. how to achieve that?

the signature that we sent via header currently looks like

```
'Authorization' : 'SharedKey {storage_account_name} : {signed_string}'
```

I have a reference of another article where they are talking about [AD and storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet). I have completed this step.

but after getting bearer token, how to use it to get ACL at storage level?

**Setup:**

After setting up application as following

[image]

I still got error while running it via Postman and Python code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results***

I registered one application in Azure AD and added API permissions for **`Azure Storage`** like below:

[image]

Make sure whether you have required permissions or not before running the query.

Now, I generated bearer token using **ROPC flow** with below parameters:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id : xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
grant_type : password
scope : https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation
username : sri@********.onmicrosoft.com
password : ******
client_secret : ************
```

[image]

After getting the **bearer** token, I ran the ***same query*** as below and got ACL in **`x-ms-acl`** response header successfully:

```json
HEAD https://<storageacc_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/testfile/path.txt?action=getAccessControl&upn=true

Authorization: Bearer <paste_bearer_token_here>
x-ms-version: 2021-06-08
```

**Response:**

[image]

Please **note** that, **Authorization** header must be  **`Bearer <token>`** while using Azure AD based authentication.

Comment: thanks for responding. this is what i was looking for. but i am stuck. I followed first step and was able to create a App and was able to get ADMIN consent for user_impersonation . I am sending my email and password (which i use to login to azure too). how to give myself permission to access that APP? fyi: i am owner of that APP (and i created it). i have correct ID and secret. but when i am trying to get token, i am getting "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50126"

Comment: What RBAC roles you currently have on your Azure account?

Comment: 4 Roles => Billing Reader @ Management group | Contributor @ Subscription level | Reader @ Subscription level | Security Reader @ Subscription level

Comment: I created one user by adding those 4 roles. By signing in with that user's account, I created one app, and I can generate token with that user's credentials. Could you please provide the screenshot of Postman with error?

Comment: added details in my original post. does it has to do anything to do with interactive login and postman not able to do it? =>https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/385629/aadsts50126-error-validating-credentials-due-to-in-1.html because if that is a reason, i am not sure i can change any setting at company wide level.

Comment: Please note that, ROPC flow only supports Azure AD user accounts that are created in AAD tenant where application is created. **Ex**: sri@tenant.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: Try creating one new Azure AD user and assign same roles to that user. Now, sign in with that new user credentials and repeat the entire process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248274/discussion-between-sridevi-and-rakesh-prasad).